# "Structure" (not recognized) expected end of statement

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a structure and the basic example for this is provided by microsoft:

```
 Private Structure employee
    Public givenName As String
    Public familyName As String
    Public phoneExtension As Long  
 End Structure
```

Trying this in a Sub im getting: "Compile error: Expected: end of statement". 
It doesnt even recognize the "Structure" keyword, the same for "Try/Catch".

Why?

FYI: I am using VBA 6.5.1054

Comment: Wrong language. You've been looking at [the documentation for VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ft0z102.aspx), not VBA. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA, Type is used. Structure(Struct) is used in C, C++ and so on.

Your code may be:

```
Private Type employee
    givenName as String
    familyName as String
    phoneExtension as Long
End Type
```

You had refferred wrong page of microsoft.

I recommend you to browse website for biginners  like http://www.excel-spreadsheet.com/vba/vba.htm .

Comment: Thank you very much, i shall pay more attention to the documentation.